# How to set enabled input in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have 3 input fields: marca (brand), modelo (model) and combustible (enginetype). I need modelo and combustible disabled initially, but set enabled when a brand (marca) is selected.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Marca</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="marca" (ionChange)="getModelos($event, marca)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona una marca...">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let marca of marcas" value="{{marca.code}}">{{marca.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>


  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Modelo</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="modelo" (ionChange)="getVersiones($event, modelo, combustible)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona un modelo..." ng-disabled="!modelo">
      <ion-option value="" selected="true">Selecciona...</ion-option>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let modelo of modelos" value="{{modelo.code}}">{{modelo.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Combustible</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="combustible" (ionChange)="itemTapped($event, combustible)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona una marca..." disabled>
    <ion-option value="" selected="true">Selecciona...</ion-option>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let combustible of combustibles" value="{{combustible.code}}">{{combustible.value}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "disabled" attribute of the ion-select and the "marca" model to achieve that:

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Marca</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="marca" (ionChange)="getModelos($event, marca)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona una marca...">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let marca of marcas" value="{{marca.code}}">{{marca.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>


  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Modelo</ion-label>
    <ion-select [disabled]="marca" [(ngModel)]="modelo" (ionChange)="getVersiones($event, modelo, combustible)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona un modelo...">
      <ion-option value="" selected="true">Selecciona...</ion-option>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let modelo of modelos" value="{{modelo.code}}">{{modelo.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Combustible</ion-label>
  <ion-select [disabled]="marca" [(ngModel)]="combustible" (ionChange)="itemTapped($event, combustible)" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecciona una marca...">
    <ion-option value="" selected="true">Selecciona...</ion-option>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let combustible of combustibles" value="{{combustible.code}}">{{combustible.value}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```